# Linear Algebra and Analysis books recommendation

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, book-recommendation

I am looking for books on these two topics at the undergraduate level, an absolute must is that they contain problems with solutions. I hate when books give you 50 exercises after a chapter and then don't provide solutions to any of them.

Alternatively, could you suggest a book for the theory part and a separate exercise book with solutions?

Comment: Im enjoying a lot *Understanding analysis* by Abbott. It dont provide solutions but you can search solutions in the net. Anyway it dont have too much exercises, just a few but very good ones.

Comment: It's pretty rare for math textbooks to have solutions. But you wouldn't have a hard time finding solutions online for any of the "standard" books for analysis or linear algebra. Naturally it's best to try to solve them yourself.

Comment: Of course I would solve them myself, but sometimes, especially when it comes to proofs it would be great for my confidence to have a solution included. So there are books with solutions to popular books? Excuse my ignorance, I'm not from an English-speaking country.

Comment: @Masacroso Actually, [all of the solutions](https://goo.gl/E2CZdr) are pretty easy to find.

Comment: I don't know if there are books of solutions, but for instance if you were to Google solutions to Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* I'm sure you'd find plenty.

Comment: @carmichael561 There are several on this site and the solutions manual prepared by Roger Cooke is now [publicly available as well](https://goo.gl/D99A2V).

Comment: I quite like Elementary Linear Algebra by Howard Anton, I feel that this is a very good introductory text.

Comment: I second that Understanding analysis by Abbott, it has all the solutions I know because I have used the book. People will be up in arms about having solutions I could never understand why.

Comment: And I quite like chocolate pudding, pretzels and cheeseburgers.

Comment: Thank you for you excellent suggestions. I will check out all of them.

Answer (score 3):

Jim Hefferon's book [*Linear Algebra*](http://joshua.smcvt.edu/linearalgebra/) is provided for free, along with all of the solutions, on his website.  It also happens to be a really good introductory book (not quite *Linear Algebra Done Right* good, but I'd still put it above average).

I haven't ever read a real analysis book with solutions but a quick Google search has provided a couple:

- [*A Problem Text in Advanced Calculus*](http://web.pdx.edu/~erdman/PTAC/problemtext_pdf.pdf) by John Erdman seems to be freely available, though I don't know if he actually meant for his directory to be public or not.
- *Problems and Theorems in Analysis, Vol I and II* by Polya and Szego.  Both authors are very well known mathematicians so I'd hazard a guess that it's a pretty good book.

Comment: Thank you so much, Jim Hefferons book seems to be in the ballpark of what I'm looking for. As for  Erdman, it looks like a very comprehensive text. I know about Polya, will try to find those books, should be very good too.